# How do I prevent Android Studio from automatically collapsing my packages in project navigation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

I have run into this annoyance over and over again and have been unable to find a solution or an answer here for it:

When I create a package in my application and then add a package within it, if I do not have a file in the directory already it will auto collapse my package in the left-side navigation of Android Studio.  This prevents me from adding other sub-packages to the parent package, without manually resolving the issue within the file system.

For Example:

[image: example of collapsed navigation]

What I want is:

```
-presentation   
  -screens
     -devicescreen
         -adapters
         -presenters
         -views
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the `1:Project` view, you have `Hide Empty Middle Packages` turned ON. You need to turn it off. Once turned off it will be shown as `Compact Empty Middle Package`. Please look at the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is it.  I feel like I just asked why my tv wont turn on, and then someone asked me if it was plugged in....to which I reply of course...and then have the realization that it is not.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your update.  I prefer the Android view.  "Compact Empty Middle Package" was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChristopherRathgeb We all made that mistake :) Been there, done that.  Added a screenshot, for good documentation.

Comment: Actually, I think you have the View types backwards. Android View is the view that had it auto collapsed.  Project view is the one that had Compact Empty Middle Package as the solution.  None the less you solved my problem!

Comment: Yes, I just turned off `Compact Empty Middle Package` in the `Android` view. That's the screenshot. I actually prefer the `Android` view rather than the `Project` view, because this view gives better organizational structure.

Comment: On a fresh install of AS 3.1.4, BOTH of those views have "Hide Empty Middle Packages" on by default. it's the second part of your answer that matters.

Comment: @kaay I think you should add your comment as an answer. The above answer is not applicable in the latest AS.

Answer (score 5):

With **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1** you need to switch to **Project View** and then click on **Settings icon** from the right top side and then disable **Compact Middle Packages**  under the **Tree Appearance** and then you create your sub package folder it will not merge/collapse and work as a sub-package as we need.

[image: Disable Compact Middle Packages]

This will prevent Android Studio to automatically collapse the package and sub-package.