# Android studio suddenly shows full folder names, how to change

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Android Studio suddenly shows the full name a folder in the Project view and I don't know how to change it. I tried to change the view with the settings in the option menu in the Project view (flatten packages check/uncheck, compact empty middle packages check/uncheck), but it didn't change.

This is how my project view used to look like:

[image]

This is how it looks now:

[image]

It seems to me that every folder inside the myapp folder suddenly has the full appid + its own name as foldername.
I tried resetting Android Studio settings by using these commands (I'm a mac user):

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
```

Still no changes. My current Android Studio version is Android Studio 2.2, build number AI-145.3276617.

The only thing I did was to update to the latest stable Android 2.2 version yesterday, I don't know if this changed the way the app appears, another project (the how it used to be screenshot) didn't seem affected at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the newest stable 2.2 build. I reported the issue here, no response yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223389

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains for me, why some projects still show the correct naming of packages, the ones with the strange behavior are databinding-projects. I hope this issue is solved soon.

Answer (score 10):

Uncheck `Flattern packages`

[image]

under setting.
[image]

Comment: I tried that, and also checking/unchecking compact empty middle packages, still no change.

Comment: The issue was mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71198) for MAC and google claiming it's already solved.

Comment: Thanks for linking me that post, it still seems to appear with my installation. I updated yesterday from a dev Android 2.2. version to the latest stable version, maybe it stems from the update.

Comment: This issue appears if you have `dataBinding` enabled. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=full%20package%20name&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=222971

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33318844/4700782)

This should be what you did:

> Click on the settings icon of the Project toolbar and turn off *Compact Empty Middle Package*.

So you only need to turn it on again

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it still didn't work. With another project, I have the same settings, but it shows very differently.

Comment: @Eve I don't understand your first EDIT, Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: I want it to look like in the before screenshot, where each folder only showed its name and not parts of the application id.

Comment: @Eve this is the name of the folders, if you go in file explorer the name you see is the name of the folders. The one you covered with blue color, is the organization name, usually it is "com.example.myAppName". Btw it is really hard to resolve this because your first two screenshots are from different projects (api folder is not existing in the second). This is why it's hard to understand your goal. Can you provide two screenshots with the same folders? even custom images are ok

Comment: I updated my question and provided mock screenshots for only one application now.

Comment: @Eve ok I got it thanks. Honestly I don't even knew it was possible. "com.package.name" is the path. I have a question: you said you have a project with the view you're aiming for in this project. If you go in file explorer,does it have the "com" and the "package" folder even if they are not shown?

Comment: The structure of both projects seem to be the same and look like my first screenshot (how it should be)

Comment: @Eve ok so in both you have (in the explorer, not in android studio) "java > com > mycompany > myapp > content" but in the other projects those are not showing in android studio?

Comment: @Eve dunno why but looks like your last folder is named "com.mycompany.myapp.content". try "Refactoring > rename" or rename with explorer..If not I honestly don't know how to help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tried all of the above, and other suggestions by other SO answers. I also had everything up to date. No luck.

However, my problem originated from a specific - messy - action I made.
I was working with a library that I (imported through/was downloaded by) gradle (as a compile only dependency).

For *x* reasons, I moved the sources folder around a lot, and I ended up placing it in the root of my project (next to folders like *app*, *build*, etc). After realizing the sources themselves were linked to other dependencies, I just deleted them.
Android Studio took note of each path I moved the sources to, and when it couldn't find it in the last one, this problem arose.

**SOLUTION**
In this folder (/.idea/libraries), I found a reference xml file for the *poorly implemented* library, among other references:

```
<SOURCES>
  <!-- paths I moved the sources to -->
  <root url="..wrong path.." />
  <root url="..wrong path.." />
  ..
  <!-- legit path created by gradle -->
  <root url=".. some temp folder .." />
</SOURCES>
```

Inside the xml, I removed the aforementioned paths Android Studio took note of, rebuilt the project and bam, problem solved!

Comment: I don't have any reference file under the `.idea/libraries` directory

Comment: @RohitKhatri almost every dependency you ever had should have an xml file under this directory, containing paths to their sources, or at least that's what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Compact Middle Packages" option in project